# Is Elm's Basics.toString implementation necessarily native?

Tags: elm

I'm new to Elm, and have a basic question about the language.

The core function [`Basics.toString : a -> String`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/5.1.1/src/Basics.elm) has a native module (i.e. javascript) [implementation](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/5.1.1/src/Native/Utils.js).

It seems that *by design* Elm has no means to do run-time type inspection and no function overloading or, to put it another way, no [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism).

Am I correct in this assertion, and therefore that a native module implementation is the *only* way to implement any function like `toString` whose behaviour depends on the value of a type variable?

I'm not opposed to this, I can see simplicity such a constraint affords - I'm just wondering if I've understood things correctly!

Comment: That's correct. Elm has [no typeclasses](https://github.com/elm/compiler/issues/1039), so you'll see a few magic functions like this in the core library.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I followed that through to Evan's talk [Let's be mainstream! User focused design in Elm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYk8CKH7OhE) which was full of entertaining insights - specifically he gets into his thinking about type classes at 38:30 which really addresses this question.